# Contract not found despite deployment tx

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x, sepolia

I have a transaction using Metamask with Remix and got the following:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x912dfae59792362b3912074669318749e485360d3f3c174d5b4bff7013840018

This is my contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.7.3/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Pigfox is ERC20 {
    uint constant deployAttempt=2;
    uint balance;
    event ItemSet(bytes32 key, bytes32 value);
    event Log(string func, uint gas);
    mapping (bytes32 => bytes32) public items;

    constructor() ERC20("Pigfox", "PFX"){
        updateBalance();
    }

    // Fallback function must be declared as external.
    fallback() external payable {
        // send / transfer (forwards 2300 gas to this fallback function)
        // call (forwards all of the gas)
        emit Log("fallback", gasleft());
    }

    // Receive is a variant of fallback that is triggered when msg.data is empty
    receive() external payable {
        emit Log("receive", gasleft());
    }

    function setItem(bytes32 key, bytes32 value) external {
        items[key] = value;
        emit ItemSet(key, value);
    }

    function updateBalance() internal {
        balance += msg.value;
    }
}
```

But when I look for the deployed contract I cannot find it.

```
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/search?f=0&q=Pigfox

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/search?f=0&q=PFX
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might have to verify the contract on Etherscan to make it discoverable. There should be plenty of resources online on how to do that in Remix (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qz9PD2zttmk)